# Shortest code to cache Rxjs http request while not complete?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I'm trying to create an observable flow that fulfills the following requirements:

1. Loads data from storage *at subscribe time*
2. If the data has not yet expired, return an observable of the stored value
3. If the data *has* expired, return an HTTP request observable that uses the refresh token to get a new value *and* store it

   - If this code is reached again before the request has completed, return the same request observable
   - If this code is reached after the previous request completed or with a different refresh token, start a new request

I'm aware that there are many different answers on how to perform step (3), but as I'm trying to perform these steps together I am looking for guidance on whether the solution I've come up with is the most succinct it can be (which I doubt!).

Here's a sample demonstrating my current approach:

```
var cachedRequestToken;
var cachedRequest;

function getOrUpdateValue() {
    return loadFromStorage()
      .flatMap(data => {
        // data doesn't exist, shortcut out
        if (!data || !data.refreshtoken) 
            return Rx.Observable.empty();

        // data still valid, return the existing value
        if (data.expires > new Date().getTime())
            return Rx.Observable.return(data.value);

        // if the refresh token is different or the previous request is 
        // complete, start a new request, otherwise return the cached request
        if (!cachedRequest || cachedRequestToken !== data.refreshtoken) { 
            cachedRequestToken = data.refreshtoken;

            var pretendHttpBody = {
                value: Math.random(),
                refreshToken: Math.random(),
                expires: new Date().getTime() + (10 * 60 * 1000) // set by server, expires in ten minutes
            };

            cachedRequest = Rx.Observable.create(ob => { 
                // this would really be a http request that exchanges
                // the one use refreshtoken for new data, then saves it
                // to storage for later use before passing on the value

                window.setTimeout(() => { // emulate slow response   
                    saveToStorage(pretendHttpBody);
                    ob.next(pretendHttpBody.value);                 
                    ob.completed(); 
                    cachedRequest = null; // clear the request now we're complete
                }, 2500);
          });
        }

        return cachedRequest;
    });
}

function loadFromStorage() {
    return Rx.Observable.create(ob => {
        var storedData = {  // loading from storage goes here
            value: 15,      // wrapped in observable to delay loading until subscribed
            refreshtoken: 63, // other process may have updated this between requests
            expires: new Date().getTime() - (60 * 1000) // pretend to have already expired
        };

        ob.next(storedData);
        ob.completed();
    })
}

function saveToStorage(data) {
    // save goes here
}

// first request
getOrUpdateValue().subscribe(function(v) { console.log('sub1: ' + v); }); 

// second request, can occur before or after first request finishes
window.setTimeout(
    () => getOrUpdateValue().subscribe(function(v) { console.log('sub2: ' + v); }),
    1500);
```

Comment: You mention in the 2nd part of stage 3 parameters. Are there any parameters besides the `refreshtoken`?. Where are they passed in? How are they compared?

Comment: The only parameter is the refresh token. I'll update the question to be clearer

Comment: Thanks. Is the token mandatory or you just use it to determine if you need to issue a new backend request?

Comment: The token is mandatory. If data loaded is null or refresh token is null then it shortcuts and returns observable.empty

Comment: Can you please point me to where in the code this happens? I see only comparison of the current and new refreshToken, no null checking or observable.empty

Comment: It occurs directly before checking expired inside the flatmap. I omitted it for this example, but will add it in one hour once at a desk. Re: refresh token mandatory, I should add that the token is passed to the backend and used to locate the user's data.

Comment: Updated to include the Observable.empty() as discussed.

Comment: Thx :-) Is the saveToStorage and loadFromStorage required or if you found a way to keep them in a stream you can omit them? What/who updates the `expired` field?

Comment: The storage is required to persist the value and refresh token in case two browsers are open to the same page, or the user closes the window then comes back an hour later.  The expired field, in reality, is a time.  I'll update the example to accurately represent this :)

Comment: Okay. Sorry for the hassle, just trying to first understand all aspects of your problem

Comment: That's ok! I appreciate the detail.  I've updated to reflect an expiry time rather than an expiry flag

Comment: I would probably just make a cache layer in between that handled the timeout period, and then based the flow on whether you get back an object or not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, have a look at a working [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/zajudi/edit?js,console).

The solution is a tad different then your initial code, and I'd like to explain why. The need to keep returning to your local storage, save it, save flags (cache and token) didn't not fit for me with reactive, functional approach. The heart of the solution I gave is:

```
var data$ = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(storageMock);
var request$ = new Rx.Subject();
request$.flatMapFirst(loadFromServer).share().startWith(storageMock).subscribe(data$);
data$.subscribe(saveToStorage);

function getOrUpdateValue() {
    return data$.take(1)
      .filter(data => (data && data.refreshtoken))
      .switchMap(data => (data.expires > new Date().getTime() 
                    ? data$.take(1)
                    : (console.log('expired ...'), request$.onNext(true) ,data$.skip(1).take(1))));
}
```

The key is that `data$` holds your latest data and is always up to date, it is easily accessible by doing a `data$.take(1)`. The `take(1)` is important to make sure your subscription gets a single values and terminates (because you attempt to work in a procedural, as opposed to functional, manner). Without the `take(1)` your subscription would stay active and you would have multiple handlers out there, that is you'll handle future updates as well in a code that was meant only for the current update.

In addition, I hold a `request$` subject which is your way to start fetching new data from the server. The function works like so:

1. The filter ensures that if your data is empty or has no token, nothing passes through, similar to the `return Rx.Observable.empty()` you had.
2. If the data is up to date, it returns `data$.take(1)` which is a single element sequence you can subscribe to.
3. If not, it needs a refresh. To do so, it triggers `request$.onNext(true)` and returns `data$.skip(1).take(1)`. The `skip(1)` is to avoid the current, out dated value.

For brevity I used `(console.log('expired ...'), request$.onNext(true) ,data$.skip(1).take(1)))`. This might look a bit cryptic. It uses the js comma separated syntax which is common in minifiers/uglifiers. It executes all statements and returns the result of the last statement. If you want a more readable code, you could rewrite it like so:

```
.switchMap(data => {
  if(data.expires > new Date().getTime()){ 
    return data$.take(1);
  } else {
    console.log('expired ...');
    request$.onNext(true);
    return data$.skip(1).take(1);
  }
});
```

The last part is the usage of `flatMapFirst`. This ensures that once a request is in progress, all following requests are dropped. You can see it works in the console printout. The 'load from server' is printed several times, yet the actual sequence is invoked only once and you get a single 'loading from server done' printout. This is a more reactive oriented solution to your original refreshtoken flag checking.

Though I didn't need the saved data, it is saved because you mentioned that you might want to read it on future sessions.

A few tips on rxjs:

1. Instead of using the `setTimeout`, which can cause many problems, you can simply do `Rx.Observable.timer(time_out_value).subscribe(...)`.
2. Creating an observable is cumbersome (you even had to call `next(...)` and `complete()`). You have a much cleaner way to do this using `Rx.Subject`. Note that you have specifications of this class, the `BehaviorSubject` and `ReplaySubject`. These classes are worth knowing and can help a lot.

One last note. This was quite a challange :-) I'm not familiar with your server side code and design considerations yet the need to suppress calls felt uncomfortable to me. Unless there is a very good reason related to your backend, my natural approach would be to use flatMap and let the last request 'win', i.e. drop previous un terminated calls and set the value.

The code is rxjs 4 based (so it can run in jsbin), if you're using angular2 (hence rxjs 5), you'll need to adapt it. Have a look at [the migration guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md).

================ answers to Steve's other questions (in comments below) =======

There is [one article](https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754) I can recommend. It's title says it all :-)

As for the procedural vs. functional approach, I'd add another variable to the service:

```
let token$ = data$.pluck('refreshtoken');
```

and then consume it when needed.

My general approach is to first map my data flows and relations and then like a good "keyboard plumber" (like we all are), build the piping. My top level draft for a service would be (skipping the angular2 formalities and provider for brevity):

```
class UserService {
  data$: <as above>;
  token$: data$.pluck('refreshtoken');
  private request$: <as above>;

  refresh(){
    request.onNext(true);
  }
}
```

You might need to do some checking so the `pluck` does not fail.

Then, each component that needs the data or the token can access it directly.

Now lets suppose you have a service that needs to act on a change to the data or the token:

```
class SomeService {
  constructor(private userSvc: UserService){
    this.userSvc.token$.subscribe(() => this.doMyUpdates());
  }
}
```

If your need to synthesize data, meaning, use the data/token and some local data:

```
Rx.Observable.combineLatest(this.userSvc.data$, this.myRelevantData$)
  .subscribe(([data, myData] => this.doMyUpdates(data.someField, myData.someField));
```

Again, the philosophy is that you build the data flow and pipes, wire them up and then all you have to do is trigger stuff.

The 'mini pattern' I've come up with is to pass to a service once my trigger sequence and register to the result. Lets take for example autocomplete:

```
class ACService {
   fetch(text: string): Observable<Array<string>> {
     return http.get(text).map(response => response.json().data;
   }
}
```

Then you have to call it every time your text changes and assign the result to your component:

```
<div class="suggestions" *ngFor="let suggestion; of suggestions | async;">
  <div>{{suggestion}}</div>
</div>
```

and in your component:

```
onTextChange(text) {
  this.suggestions = acSVC.fetch(text);
}
```

but this could be done like this as well:

```
class ACService {
   createFetcher(textStream: Observable<string>): Observable<Array<string>> {
     return textStream.flatMap(text => http.get(text))
       .map(response => response.json().data;
   }
}
```

And then in your component:

```
textStream: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
suggestions: Observable<string>;

constructor(private acSVC: ACService){
  this.suggestions = acSVC.createFetcher(textStream);
}

onTextChange(text) {
  this.textStream.next(text);
}
```

template code stays the same.

It seems like a small thing here, but once the app grows bigger, and the data flow complicated, this works much better. You have a sequence that holds you data and you can use it around the component wherever you need it, you can even further transform it. For example, lets say you need to know the number of suggestions, in the first method, once you get the result, you need to further query it to get it, thus:

```
onTextChange(text) {
  this.suggestions = acSVC.fetch(text);
  this.suggestionsCount = suggestions.pluck('length'); // in a sequence
  // or
  this.suggestions.subscribe(suggestions => this.suggestionsCount = suggestions.length); // in a numeric variable.
}
```

Now in the second method, you just define:

```
constructor(private acSVC: ACService){
  this.suggestions = acSVC.createFetcher(textStream);
  this.suggestionsCount = this.suggestions.pluck('length');
}
```

Hope this helps :-)

While writing, I tried to reflect about the path I took to getting to use reactive like this. Needless to say that on going experimentation, numerous jsbins and strange failures are big part of it. Another thing that I think helped shape my approach (though I'm not currently using it) is learning redux and reading/trying a bit of ngrx (angular's redux port). The philosophy and the approach does not let you even think procedural so you have to tune in to functional, data, relations and flows based mindset.

Comment: Wow Meir, thank you!  This is all very informative.  I can see how you've flipped the design on its head to achieve what I could only do through micromanaging the behaviour.  I can only send the request to the server once because the refresh token is consumed server side when the request is received and future requests with the same token would return 400, so it felt "right" to make the client side request once and have the rest join onto it.

Comment: You mention that I attempt to work procedurally.  The service that exposes the getOrUpdateValue() is used by other services to take the value and use it in other requests (in reality, the value is an access token).  Would you have handled this differently in Rx?  Do you have any accessible "recommended reading" for getting into the Rx mindset?

Comment: Thanks Meir, literally couldn't ask for more :)

Comment: Glad I could help. And remember rx is fun, it is like solving sophisticated puzzles all day long ;-)
And thx for the challenge

Comment: I have read through all the material you have provided and am much, much more reactive in my design now.  I have a couple questions, though.  

(1) If we did not `take(1)` on `data$` in `getOrUpdateValue()` and the token was always expired, would this result in an infinite loop of pushing values into itself?   

(2) Does `skip(1)` wait until the source (`request$`) pushes a new value before continuing?

(3) Am I correct in thinking that the `startsWith()` on `request$` renders the default value of `subject$` redundant as it'll be instantly replaced, or is there a nuance I'm missing?

Comment: Ahhh, you hit the dark side of reactive :-) The dependencies and flow might become hard to follow. Look for an article by stalz about how to debug rxjs. You can always add in the pipe a .do(...) to see what's going through your pipe. A quick tip, instead of an arrow function .do((v) => console.log('data is: ', v)) you can .do(console.log.bind(console, 'data is:')) or even define a helper: function labelPrint(label: string){ return function(value){ console.log(label, value);}}

Comment: As for the first question, I don't think so (though have to see the final code), that's because on the first hit of expired data you will issue a new request which will end up updating your data so successive calls will see the new data.

Comment: Second question: skip(1) ignores the immediate available value and then halts till a new value is emitted, this comes to ignore the out of data data you already have.

Comment: Third question: it isn't, note in the jsbin sample that the first calls (untill expiration) get the first element (token is 1000). The start with is actually on the mapped sequence request$.flatMapFirst(loadFromServer).share() (which is not the request$). This is a new Observable which is the result of the request triggering a server call, then we tell it to have as a first value your existing, initial, data. The request$ itself is not affected. If you had for debug a request$.subscribe(console.log.bind(console, '>> new request >>') you'd notice it doesn't get triggered by the startWith call.

Comment: Ok cool, thanks very much.  There is definitely a lot to get my head around!  I'm currently looking at reworking my service so all the save/load and routing operations are appropriate external parties observing the data stream, and the getOrUpdate() method is just a utility method equivalent to PumpOnce() for things that just need one, up to date value (further http calls that depend on that value, for instance).

Comment: And again, if you can afford it, avoid the caching and move to flatMapLatest (or switchMapLatest). This will add a few calls to your BE and drop the early ones, yet make your code simpler. Also have a look at debounce and throttle, they are very useful. Just make sure you don't do not create a starvation with debounce.

Comment: I have one final question (I believe!) and that is there a variant of flatMap that says "prefer those without errors"?  

I don't mind requests going to the server and failing, but since I know that the first received will be the only one not to return 400 for a given token, I need the client-side code to prefer that one (and still continue to do flatMapLatest type things with the successful ones in case of concurrent valid requests)

Comment: Here's a jsbin of my current approach if it interests you http://jsbin.com/larovagepo/edit?js,console

Comment: Why last? Keep them coming. Not sure the 'prefer' is built in and anyways the switchMap drops previous ones. My initial thought would be to use flatMap (without the latest), then buffer the results, once your buffer emitted you have an array of responses, traverse them backwards, finding the last success or if there isn't any, the last error. But this requires that you come up with a good buffering schema. You can either do it by time or use debounce. If you choose debounce, make sure you don't have an ongoing flow of requests that will create starvation.

Comment: Had a look at the jsbin, looks nice, obviously you're having fun, I can hear your wheels spinning :-)
Couldn't follow all the details. One small note, when you return an observable (for example, loadFromserver), add .take(1). This way you'll have an automatic subscription and not leave dangling subscriptions all around. They have a nasty nature of coming back to bite you

Comment: Good thought, thanks.  I need the latest as I now incorporate logging out into that same request pipeline, so that when a logout request occurs it dumps all in-progress token requests with it.  Otherwise the logout clears the token and the reply from the refresh server for an older request restores it (which breaks the flow).

I'll take a look and rethink my strategy.  Thanks for all of your help, you've definitely given me the tools to move ahead.